# Login Form With Fingerprint Sensor Using VB6 And Arduino UNO

Tags: arduino, vb6, fingerprint

How can I interface my Fingerprint Sensor using VB6? I've already made a login form  but I need help using the fingerprint sensor for the security. Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Consult your fingerprint scanner documentation.

Comment: how? i didn't know how to  do it? @GSerg

Comment: You open the little brochure that came with the fingerprint scanner and you read it. Or you go to the manufacturer's website, locate the manual and read it.

Comment: then after that? how can i connect it to my login form?

Comment: It tells you that in the manual.

Comment: @GSerg i can't find the manual :(

Comment: Google the name of your fingerprint reader, you should be able to find the manufacturer's website. There you should be able to find a user guide or programming guide, maybe even code samples

Comment: What model fingerprint reader is it?

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville I'm using a r307 fingerprint sensor attached through arduino.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good starting point: [Getting Started with Optical Fingerprint Reader – R305](https://www.rhydolabz.com/wiki/?p=15770). It's for the 305 but the overall setup should be very similar if not identical. Most importantly you will find an **SDK for R30X modules** in the Resources section of this page. It includes drivers, demos (with source code), SYNO API, user manual, etc.

Also, Vishnu M Aiea wrote a C++ library to handle communication with the R307 sensor: [R30X Arduino Library](https://github.com/vishnumaiea/R30X-Fingerprint-Sensor-Library). You should consider using this to handle the communication aspect since it's already been built for you. You might need to get it compiled into a DLL to use with VB6.

There's also an article he wrote about the whole setup process: [Interfacing R307 Optical Fingerprint Scanner with Arduino](https://vishnumaiea.in/projects/hardware/interfacing-r307-optical-fingerprint-scanner-with-arduino)

These links thoroughly explain how to set everything up. I think with all this information you should be able to make a lot of progress and come back to Stack Overflow with more specific questions.